# BabylonJS Collision Detection, Overlapping Meshes

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, babylonjs

In the following example: http://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#1NASOD#13

Why does the sphere mesh overlap (or fall slightly into) the box mesh as the box moves upwards?  Is there a way to make the sphere not overlap the box as the box moves the sphere upwards?

For reference, here is the relevant code from the example:

```
var createScene = function () {

    // This creates a basic Babylon Scene object (non-mesh)
    var scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);

    // This creates and positions a free camera (non-mesh)
    var camera = new BABYLON.FreeCamera("camera1", new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 10, -20), scene);

    // This targets the camera to scene origin
    camera.setTarget(BABYLON.Vector3.Zero());

    // This attaches the camera to the canvas
    camera.attachControl(canvas, true);

    // This creates a light, aiming 0,1,0 - to the sky (non-mesh)
    var light = new BABYLON.HemisphericLight("light1", new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 1, 0), scene);

    // Default intensity is 1. Let's dim the light a small amount
    light.intensity = 0.7;

    // Our built-in 'sphere' shape. Params: name, subdivs, size, scene
    var sphere = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateSphere("sphere1", 8, 2, scene);

    // Move the sphere upward 1/2 its height
    sphere.position.y = 2;

    var ground = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateBox("box1",2.0, scene);
    ground.position.y = -1;

    sphere.material = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("s-mat", scene);

    scene.enablePhysics(new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

    sphere.physicsImpostor = new BABYLON.PhysicsImpostor(sphere, BABYLON.PhysicsImpostor.SphereImpostor, { mass: 1, restitution: 0 }, scene);
    ground.physicsImpostor = new BABYLON.PhysicsImpostor(ground, BABYLON.PhysicsImpostor.BoxImpostor, { mass: 0, restitution: 0 }, scene);

    scene.registerBeforeRender(function () {
        if(ground.position.y <= 2.5){
            ground.position.y += .05;
        }
        sphere.physicsImpostor.setLinearVelocity(new BABYLON.Vector3(0,0,0));
        sphere.physicsImpostor.setAngularVelocity(new BABYLON.Quaternion(0,0,0,0));
    });

    return scene;

};
```